Ошибка в vs code при команде rebase
В vs code при команде rebase в консоли появляется ошибка:
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait --reuse-window'
Как ее исправить? В сети нашла только команду:
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
но это не помогает

Что выводит команда: git config -l --show-origin | grep editor

@Komdosh file:C:/Users/plokh/.gitconfig  core.editor=code --wait

@Komdosh чуть ранее я пыталась сделать одну настройку (чтобы команда yarn запускалась без npx)  и запустила в командной строке "setx PATH "%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%.yarn\bin"". Это могло как-то сбить настройки?

не, вроде всё нормально с этим, хм попробуйте ещё git config --global core.editor "code"

или может там ещё больше ошибка есть?

@Komdosh ввела указанную вами команду и попробовала снова вызвать интерактивный rebase, и получила такую ошибку:
"c:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe" -C "c:/Drive/Programming/Tests/Korus" -c "core.editor=code --wait --reuse-window" -c "sequence.editor=code --wait --reuse-window" rebase --interactive de314571d5ec35fe71a0688b490ad39659e2a01d
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait --reuse-window: code: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait --reuse-window'.

а всё таки похоже что path неправильный и он потерял команду code на системе.

Зайдите в настройки переменных окружения системы и проверьте, что VS Code там есть и пути все правильные без кавычек и прочего

@Komdosh да, действительно, поменяла путь в переменной среды path и всё заработало)  спасибо большое за помощь!

Рад что смог помочь :)

Не меняйте ничего в переменных окружения, прописывайте полный путь к исполняему файлу в настройках git.
